# Analytic KPIs for Enterprise Mobile Applications

Tags: mobile-application, enterprise

We are in process of creating a Mobile KPI framework - which would cater to needs of all in-house developed Mobile Apps. What we are looking at is:

1. Executive Dashboard
2. Dashboard for Customer of Apps

Can we get some idea about what should be the KPIs for enterprise mobile Applications? We do have some on the lines of

Engagement, Retention, and Task Completion!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're going about this in the wrong way.

I'm sure you can find a list on the internet somewhere of "important metrics to track", but what you should really care about is "what am I trying to learn?" In general, we:

Build  → Measure  → Learn

But to properly execute a single cycle of the "build, measure, learn" feedback loop, we have to go backwards. We must know the questions we are trying to answer (what we're trying to learn), to better understand the metrics we should track, and the metrics we're trying to track heavily influence what it is we're going to build.

So ask yourself:

- What are my assumptions?

  - If I change feature X, I expect more users to sign up.
- What metrics do I need to track in order to prove my hypothesis?

Comment: Thanks Daniel; and that is precisely I am here to know the 'Right Path'. Thanks for the share. Let me explain little more context; we create Mobile Apps for our business and Functions, example Admin, Fin, or say HR...and many other. Hence it becomes essential to measure the effectiveness of our App - which in our case is not a consumer App!


Our primary goals are around measuring UX, Funnel Completion, Retention (Based on type of App). What I am looking at is - a standard framework for measuring KPIs - and what type of! The learning for us is different for different Apps! Hope this helps!

Comment: "A key performance indicator (KPI) is a business metric used to evaluate factors that are crucial to the success of an organization. KPIs differ per organization; business KPIs may be net revenue or a customer loyalty metric, while government might consider unemployment rates."  So... What factors are crucial to your businesses success? What _can_ you track to measure those factors?